# Why does Elaina leave the flower field?

Tags: wandering-witch-journey-of-elaina

In episode 3, after finding the soldier and his (presumably deceased) sister getting eaten by the flowers, Elaina simply leaves without a word. This naturally left me puzzled as to why, as it feels quite cold and heartless. Is there simply nothing she can do at this point? And does it not cross her mind to at least destroy the whole place so there are no more victims in the future? I would guess this would probably be easy to answer with the novels, but I haven't read them. Does she elaborate on her decision there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm deriving an answer from the manga, since I still have yet to have a chance to read the light novels.

The manga adds a bit of narration compared to the anime, and it does indeed give the impression there's nothing Elaina could do. Not only that, but it offers more insight into the guard Solor's and his sister Artemisia's relationship. Solor seems a bit obsessed with her, and it might be crueler to make Solor continue living without his sister.

Most importantly, after learning how the flower field is poisonous, Elaina resolves to go and try and save Artemisia, indicating she at least intended to help.

From chapter 2:

> When I leave tomorrow, I'll stop by that field and try to persuade her to go home. If the "poison" is a spell, there may be a way to break it. And if I break it, I'll have discharged any obligations then.

And at the end, Artemisia is obviously gone, but even though Solor is still alive and talking, Elaina seems to conclude there's no hope (emphasis mine).

> Just one day ago, that thing had still been his sister. She had lost her body, her mind, everything, somewhere in the flower field. Maybe, just as the witch had cleared the land, sown seeds... and grown flowers with a spell... the flower field was luring people with its magic and attempting to grow humans. [...] All that remains is the fact that those two can **never be parted**. Ironically, they looked like a love-binding flower.

Answer (score 2):

No she just leaves. It not really explained why she didn't do anything. Also the slave girl Nino in the Manga kills the Chief then kills herself.